# Is it possible to maintain a git submodule under multiple paths?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a `.gitmodules` file with something similar to this:

```
[submodule "my_submodule"]
    path   = vendor/my_submodule
    url    = # whatever
    branch = # whatever
```

Because of repo's structure refactoring reasons, I need to keep temporarily this module in that path but also in another one, say, `modules/my_submodule`.

Is it possible to maintain the submodule in two different paths at the same time? Something like this:

```
[submodule "my_submodule"]
    path   = ["vendor/my_submodule", "modules/my_submodule"] 
    url    = # whatever
    branch = # whatever
```

Comment: When I tried this, I had two submodule sections, `[submodule "vendor/my_submodule"]` and `[submodule "modules/my_submodule"]` - but otherwise no problems. If the two submodules need to be in sync, you could move it to the new location and symlink to the old location.